# Como hago para filtrar los archivos segun su type? React, axios. js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, react-axios

La Api que espera el llamado le agregaron una const {type} = req.query;

```
async function getFiles(req, res) {
  const { type } = req.query;
  const files = await QualificationFile.find({ qualification: 
  req.params.id, type });
  if (!files.length) {
    return res.send([]);
  }
```

Y yo al hacer al llamado a services "uploadFile" le tengo que agregar ese type y en getFiles
obtenerlo segun type "documentations"

```
uploadFile(id, fileObject = {}, onUploadProgress ,endpoint = 'tasks') {
const {file, qualificationtype} = fileObject.file? fileObject : {file: fileObject, qualificationtype: null};

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
formData.append('qualificationType', qualificationtype)

const url = `/${endpoint}/${id}/files`;
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  axios
    .post(url, formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      onUploadProgress,
    })
    .then((data) => {
      resolve(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
});
```

Y al llamarlo con getfiles filtrarlo segun el type que quiero.

```
 getFiles(id, endpoint = 'tasks', type = null) {
const url = `/${endpoint}/${id}/files`;
const params = encodeQuery({ qualificationType: 'documentations' });
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const array = [];
  axios.get(`${url}/${params}`).then((response) => {
    response.map((file) => {
      if (file.qualificationType === type) {
        array.push(file);
      }
    });
    console.log(response);
    response = array;
    console.log(response);
    resolve(response);
  });
});
```

**El mayor problema que tengo es que a veces me lo sube con type "documentations" y a veces sin ningún tipo es decir "null" al subir el/los archivo. Creo que la falla esta en el uploadFile o al llamar al uploadfile desde el componente ya que el getfiles siempre me trae lo que le pido.**.

**Aca quiero obtener los que tienen type documentations**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**y aca quiero obtener los que se subieron sin el type documentations es decir type null.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego el llamado a getfiles en donde le paso como tercer parametro "documentations" asi type queda como type = 'documentations" y no null al hacer el llamado.

```
const getFiles = (qualificationId) => {
    fileService.getFiles(qualificationId, 'qualifications', 'documentations').then((files) => {
      setExistingFiles(files);
    });
  };
```

Subi 2 archivos, uno me lo puso como documentations y me lo filtro bien pero el otro no.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el codigo al hacer el llamado a uploadFile

```
  const uploadFiles =  (qualificationId) => {
    const fileRequests = [];
    const actionStructure = { title: 'Subiendo Archivo', progress: 0, name: '' };
    files.map((file, i) => {
      if (!(file instanceof File)) {
        return;
      }
      fileRequests.push(
        fileService.uploadFile(
          qualificationId,
          {file: file, qualificationtype: 'documentations'},
          (e) => {
            file.progress = Math.round((100 * e.loaded) / e.total);
            const actionsAux = [...actionInProgress];
            const fileActionProgressIndex = actionsAux.findIndex((item) => item.name === file.name || item.name === '');
            if (fileActionProgressIndex) {
              actionsAux[fileActionProgressIndex] = { ...actionsAux[fileActionProgressIndex], progress: file.progress };
            } else {
              actionsAux.push({ ...actionStructure, progress: file.progress, name: file.name});
            }
            // setActionInProgress(actionsAux);
          },
          'qualifications',
        )
      );
    });
    return Promise.all(fileRequests)
      .then((_) => {
        setActionInProgress([{ title: 'Subiendo Archivo ', progress: 100, name: '' }]);
        Notify.success('Archivos subidos correctamente');
       
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        Notify.failure(`Error al subir archivos: ${err}`);
        
      });
  };
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el código como texto. Así es más fácil ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Perdón es la primera ves que utilizo el foro. Realmente necesito una mano si podes. gracias amigo. Ahi agregue el codigo. Si falto otros codigos los pongo pasa que no quiero dejarlo muy grande tampoco.

Comment: Bienvenido! No se trata de dejar o no muy grande la pregunta, se trata de proveer un [example]. Te recomiendo que leas tambien [ask]

Comment: Dale muchas gracias amigo voy a revisarlo y mejorar para la proxima. Tenes idea como al hacer el uploadfile puedo agregarle que sea de tipo documentations?, y en otros caso dejarlo como null.

Comment: Quizás te sirva leer sobre que es `req.query` 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417592/node-js-difference-between-req-query-and-req-params porque veo que no estás usando ningún query param en tu ruta

Comment: No logro entender cuál es el error/problema sinceramente. Disculpa

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, realmente aprecio el tiempo que te tomas para darme una mano. Deje una imagen a lo ultimo que es justamente lo que estoy buscando realizar. Que me lo ponga como qualificationtype = "documentations" y no como null.

Comment: En el último bloque de código de tu pregunta, tienes la siguiente condición `if (file.qualificationType === type)` donde `type` es `null` por defecto (Según como se declarar en la función `getFiles(id, endpoint = 'tasks', type = null)`) por lo que si algún `file.qualificationType` es efectivamente `null` entonces también se agregará al array de la respuesta

Comment: No no seria null porque al hacer el llamado a getfiles le paso ese type que sea igual a documentations. Como pego el llamado por aca?

Comment: Todo lo que sea relevante agrégalo a la pregunta por favor. Te recomiendo nuevamente si puedes centrarte en hacer un [example]. La idea sería que cualquiera que vea tu pregunta sea capaz de reproducir tu problema :) Es decir, intenta agregar todo el código que forme parte del problema. Ej: Si hay un llamado a una API, entonces agrega la parte de la API que maneja el llamado y la parte de la app que realiza el llamado.

Comment: Bien voy a ir arreglandolo y para la proxima subirlo mejor. Pasa que realmente necesito solucionar el problema disculpa. Agregue el codigo solicitado.

Comment: No hay problema, creo que encontre una posible causa del error. Cuando haces `axios.get(\`${url}/${params}\`)` debería ser `axios.get(\`${url}?${params}\`)` Es decir, está mal la URL, debes poner un signo de pregunta `?` no un slash `/`

Comment: Lo verifico y ya te respondo. (Ojala sea eso). Lo que me hace dudar es que creo que el problema esta cuando hago el llamado a uploadfile y le paso los parametros. Dejo el codigo despues de probar por las dudas. Obviamente que si esto funciona lo cerramos aca no mas jaja

Comment: De Filtrarlos los filtra bien. Lo que no hace bien es al subir el archivo ponermelo como "documentations".  Porque algunas veces lo hace y otras no. Deje la imagen de ejemplo de los dos archivos que subi y el codigo de uploadfile arriba

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142559/discussion-between-andres-gardiol-and-martin-eduardo-aguayo).